# JAVA:the first output is difficult to understand

Tags: java

[![enter image description here][1]][1]In my opinion,the first output should be "hello",but why the first output is "world" ?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello");
        test();
    }
    public static void test() {
        System.out.println("world");
        main(null);
        System.out.println("!");
    }
   }


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXSHY.png
```

Comment: There is no image.  Try copying and pasting both the code and the output as text, it works much better.

Comment: It isn't. This program recursively prints hello and world in that order.

Comment: The first word printed is "hello". [See here](https://ideone.com/i14mUJ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `main` method is run by default. It is run first. Inside the main method, it:

- prints `"hello"`
- calls the `test()` method

In the `test()` method, it:

- prints `"world"`
- calls the `main()` method

And the process repeats, resulting in a [StackOverflowError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214741/what-is-a-stackoverflowerror).

The `main` method was run first, so the order of events is as so:

- prints `"hello"`
- calls the `test()` method
- prints '"world"`
- calls the `main()` method

Therefore it prints `"hello"` first.

Comment: I run this program in Eclipse,  but the first output is "world",not "hello".

Comment: @super_man Either you haven't scrolled to the top of the console, or you ran the `test()` method by default.